# How to convert inputrstream or string to Exception?

Tags: java, exception, inputstream

I tried to execute jar from Java code with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("java -jar a.jar")
```

I could get InputStream with error from `Process.getErrorStream()`.

Can I take this stream and if it has an Exception transform it to Exception and throw in my upper application?

Has Java some mechanism to convert string to Exception?

**EDIT:** Or maybe java has some mechanism like `System.exit(int code)` but with Exception? So in parent app I can do something like `process.waitFor()` but take an exception instead int code?

Comment: You can always construct a [new RuntimeException Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html#RuntimeException(java.lang.String)) and throw it.

Comment: But how to catch it if i run jar like a process in another application?
I can only take a stream of error explained nor error.

Or maybe has another way to run jar file in java code?

Answer (score 0):

`Process.getErrorStream()` returns an `IntputStream` connected to the error output of the subprocess.

So, it is not exception in Java terms. It's an output information which must be considered as an error detected by the process during its execution.
Java don't convert automatically InputStream or String to Exception.

So, you could read this stream in a String and throw  a custom exception with as message the string. 
If you want that the caller may be able to handle this exception in a clean way, don't use a `RuntimeException` but a checked exception :

```
public class ProcessExecutionException extends Exception{
   public ProcessExecutionException(String errorOutputMsg){
      super(errorOutputMsg);
   }
}
```

**Edit for answering your comment :**

> Yeah, but how to check is inputstream line is a part of stacktrace of
>   child exception

it's not a stracktrace but error messages as explained.

> and how much line from IS i should add to ProcessExecutionException?`

You have to read all the errorStream until it returns null if you want to capture all error output.

> In my case my jar is a Spring Application and it write to error stream
>   nor only Exception that i really need to catch, also some information
>   like "Error, you have no sl4j xml file, etc - like example". And i
>   need only really important exception

How the classes producing errors in output may guess if it is important for you or not ?
You must decide yourself which error message pattern should be considered as an important error or not.
Personally, if when my process is run, I have a not well configured logger, I will kill it and correct this problem before starting it again.

If you have input in the ErroStream, you can also inspect the value of the `Process.exitCode()` (`0`: normal termination, else problem). 
If it is different from `0`, you can suspect that it not only a little problem.

Here, some tracks to try.

> Can i return something to exit like in System.exit()

In the child process, you can try to intercept all exceptions not handled which may be triggered . You can do it whatever the way (aspect, global try/catch, filter...) .
In this way, if you intercept an exception not handled and that you consider that the application must be terminated, you can do a `System.exit` with the expected code by the parent process.
In this way, in the parent, if `Process.exitCode()` matchs with expected code for important exception, you can handle it as you wish.

Comment: Yeah, but how to check is inputstream line is a part of stacktrace of child exception?
And how much line from IS i should add to ProcessExecutionException?

In my case my jar is a Spring Application and it write to error stream nor only Exception that i really need to catch, also some information like "Error, you have no sl4j xml file, etc - like example".
And i need only really important exception.

And how about second part of question?
Can i return something to exit like in System.exit()?